# Why aren't all the backslashes being replaced as per replace() statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace backslashes (from this [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)) with double backslashes.

My Script:

```
txt = "qnkyHbgFYhBi@lFA|@Dz@K~@Oz@An@Dz@A|@D|@M|BJZd@KDHRzBf@lMNrBB~@Lz@\h@^`@Lt@?L]`@GH?FJl@Xl@NNLXVpBHV^LZf@Jt@@j@Kx@OjB@l@b@ZJDv@d@`@RXFp@\Zl@d@|Ad@`@jAzBf@nATn@\xAD~@Jt@TJTv@^b@f@^b@b@f@^r@nA`@^\f@`@VVp@Lx@Vb@d@n@\l@V|BLx@Hz@Pp@Lz@Fl@ErAFf@K~@IvBQr@m@hBFfAC|@g@nC?z@ANi@hBGjAMx@OvBa@hBWfBSx@?r@M|@Qv@Wn@q@tAMt@@z@Px@kAvDWj@u@pAYr@Mx@q@fA_@d@K~@YTAr@C@@B@`@ITSL}@I]vBz@pA@z@KVGDk@@g@Eg@Kg@@g@Ec@Fe@YSZGFEUUg@Gz@i@j@S|@Wr@Sp@[hBDx@BvBD~@BvCNx@Zj@Z^Zf@TXb@R^Z\`@f@FXj@BTOdA]`BUx@Wl@Oz@G|@Hn@At@m@lI@XXf@?v@IBCq@M_AV{B\wGLs@To@|@Th@In@`@@cBWmAuAeE[k@e@YYg@a@_@c@YQ[y@aAWa@Us@?iAEk@?{@KaFNy@d@qBh@eDl@s@J@JMLKLT`@R`@\X~@b@^^PfAr@\Lf@Fd@m@J{ABkALw@d@a@?_AMoA?yCbAqC@s@hBwBXi@Ng@Nu@n@sAMuBJ}@\kACs@[e@Wk@e@c@k@YYYIBi@eAMy@A}@Im@G}@JyBDyB?{@IyBC_AKc@_@QgAa@]m@eAo@]e@Om@SsAIy@GwDIwB@}BF}BC]AcEIq@Wq@i@eBMy@AkBUyDIKEvAIZUNK?MFc@ZUGKeAG}@M{DLgAD_ADiFHKtBITm@By@OS[QAUF}@PeBA}AIe@GQc@g@UaBUs@}@gAKi@Ns@A[Kw@GS]g@Ws@I}BOwB?{@SqDA_AQwDAw@g@DEGAu@B}BA}@Fy@Re@Hw@A_AUiAH{@RYXk@EwBG{@OiAAmA"

x = txt.replace("\\", "\\\\")

print(x)
```

Output (top string has spaces added to highlight the differences to the orginal string below)

```
qnkyHbgFYhBi@lFA|@Dz@K~@Oz@An@Dz@A|@D|@M|BJZd@KDHRzBf@lMNrBB~@Lz@\\h@^`@Lt@?L]`@GH?FJl@Xl@NNLXVpBHV^LZf@Jt@@j@Kx@OjB@l@b@ZJDv@d@`@RXFp@\\Zl@d@|Ad@`@jAzBf@nATn@­~    @Jt@TJTv@^b@f@^b@b@f@^r@nA`@^@`    @VVp@Lx@Vb@d@n@\\ l@V|BLx@Hz@Pp@Lz@Fl@ErAFf@K~@IvBQr@m@hBFfAC|@g@nC?z@ANi@hBGjAMx@OvBa@hBWfBSx@?r@M|@Qv@Wn@q@tAMt@@z@Px@kAvDWj@u@pAYr@Mx@q@fA_@d@K~@YTAr@C@@B@`@ITSL}@I]vBz@pA@z@KVGDk@@g@Eg@Kg@@g@Ec@Fe@YSZGFEUUg@Gz@i@j@S|@Wr@Sp@[hBDx@BvBD~@BvCNx@Zj@Z^Zf@TXb@R^Z\\`@f@FXj@BTOdA]`BUx@Wl@Oz@G|@Hn@At@m@lI@XXf@?v@IBCq@M_AV{B\\wGLs@To@|@Th@In@`@@cBWmAuAeE[k@e@YYg@a@_@c@YQ[y@aAWa@Us@?iAEk@?{@KaFNy@d@qBh@eDl@s@J@JMLKLT`@R`@\\X~@b@^^PfAr@\\Lf@Fd@m@J{ABkALw@d@a@?_AMoA?yCbAqC@s@hBwBXi@Ng@Nu@n@sAMuBJ}@\\kACs@[e@Wk@e@c@k@YYYIBi@eAMy@A}@Im@G}@JyBDyB?{@IyBC_AKc@_@QgAa@]m@eAo@]e@Om@SsAIy@GwDIwB@}BF}BC]AcEIq@Wq@i@eBMy@AkBUyDIKEvAIZUNK?MFc@ZUGKeAG}@M{DLgAD_ADiFHKtBITm@By@OS[QAUF}@PeBA}AIe@GQc@g@UaBUs@}@gAKi@Ns@A[Kw@GS]g@Ws@I}BOwB?{@SqDA_AQwDAw@g@DEGAu@B}BA}@Fy@Re@Hw@A_AUiAH{@RYXk@EwBG{@OiAAmA

qnkyHbgFYhBi@lFA|@Dz@K~@Oz@An@Dz@A|@D|@M|BJZd@KDHRzBf@lMNrBB~@Lz@\ h@^`@Lt@?L]`@GH?FJl@Xl@NNLXVpBHV^LZf@Jt@@j@Kx@OjB@l@b@ZJDv@d@`@RXFp@\ Zl@d@|Ad@`@jAzBf@nATn@\ xAD~@Jt@TJTv@^b@f@^b@b@f@^r@nA`@^\f@`@VVp@Lx@Vb@d@n@\      l@V|BLx@Hz@Pp@Lz@Fl@ErAFf@K~@IvBQr@m@hBFfAC|@g@nC?z@ANi@hBGjAMx@OvBa@hBWfBSx@?r@M|@Qv@Wn@q@tAMt@@z@Px@kAvDWj@u@pAYr@Mx@q@fA_@d@K~@YTAr@C@@B@`@ITSL}@I]vBz@pA@z@KVGDk@@g@Eg@Kg@@g@Ec@Fe@YSZGFEUUg@Gz@i@j@S|@Wr@Sp@[hBDx@BvBD~@BvCNx@Zj@Z^Zf@TXb@R^Z\ `@f@FXj@BTOdA]`BUx@Wl@Oz@G|@Hn@At@m@lI@XXf@?v@IBCq@M_AV{B\ wGLs@To@|@Th@In@`@@cBWmAuAeE[k@e@YYg@a@_@c@YQ[y@aAWa@Us@?iAEk@?{@KaFNy@d@qBh@eDl@s@J@JMLKLT`@R`@\ X~@b@^^PfAr@\ Lf@Fd@m@J{ABkALw@d@a@?_AMoA?yCbAqC@s@hBwBXi@Ng@Nu@n@sAMuBJ}@\ kACs@[e@Wk@e@c@k@YYYIBi@eAMy@A}@Im@G}@JyBDyB?{@IyBC_AKc@_@QgAa@]m@eAo@]e@Om@SsAIy@GwDIwB@}BF}BC]AcEIq@Wq@i@eBMy@AkBUyDIKEvAIZUNK?MFc@ZUGKeAG}@M{DLgAD_ADiFHKtBITm@By@OS[QAUF}@PeBA}AIe@GQc@g@UaBUs@}@gAKi@Ns@A[Kw@GS]g@Ws@I}BOwB?{@SqDA_AQwDAw@g@DEGAu@B}BA}@Fy@Re@Hw@A_AUiAH{@RYXk@EwBG{@OiAAmA
```

So you can see
`@\xAD~@`
becomes
`@­~@`
when I would expect it to be
`@\\xAD~@`.

Comment: `\xAD` is an escape sequence, there's no backslash in the string.

Comment: `\xAD` is a character whose code is the hex value `AD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that there are no backslashes in your string.  Your source code has backslashes, but they are all escape signals.  If you want to retain the backslashes in "WYSIWYG" style, use `raw` string mode:

```
txt = r"qnkyHbgFYhB..."
```

This will retain the characters as seen, without processing the usual escape sequences.